# Can I redraw point first created with getTransform() at the correct coordinates?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, coordinates

I have an application with multiple canvas layers.

Let's simplify it and say that I have two layers, one for a base image and the other one where you can draw.

This is my html:

```
    <div
        className="canvas-wrapper2"
        style={{ position: 'relative', height: '80vh' }}
        onWheel={zoomHandler}
        onMouseMove={mouseMoveHandler}
        onMouseDown={mouseDownHandler}
        onMouseUp={mouseUpHandler}
    >
        {imgReady && <ImageCanvas ref={imageRef} image={image} />}
        {imgReady &&
        maskReady && (
                <MaskCanvas ref={maskRef} backgroundImage={image} image={maskImage} />
        )}
    </div>
```

On both canvas you can zoom and drag. The zoom works from anywhere on the mask.

Currently I am getting my coordinates with this method:

```
const getTransformedPoint = (x, y) => {
    const originalPoint = new DOMPoint(x, y);
    return context.getTransform().invertSelf().transformPoint(originalPoint);
};
```

which is called onMouseMove like this:

```
getTransformedPoint(event.nativeEvent.offsetX, event.nativeEvent.offsetY)
```

on the MaskCanvas I implemented a draw function like:

```
const drawHandler = () => {
    const middle = brushSize / 2;
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillRect(
        currentTransformedCursor.x - middle,
        currentTransformedCursor.y - middle,
        brushSize,
        brushSize
    );


    const point = {
        x: currentTransformedCursor.x - middle,
        y: currentTransformedCursor.y - middle,
        w: brushSize
    };

    setMaskData((previous) => [ ...previous, point ]);
};
```

where ***currentTransformedCursor*** is the result of ***getTransformedPoint*** called onMouseMove

It works perfectly fine but the drawing disappear every time I zoom in/out or I drag.
This is why I am creating the maskData. which is defined like this:

```
const [ maskData, setMaskData ] = useState([]);
```

If you're not familiar with react

setMaskData((previous) => [ ...previous, point ]);

means that I have a variable maskData, it's an empty array, and everytime setMaskData is called I add a new 'point' to the maskData. It will reload my component.

and then, in order to draw the points after my context change I do

```
const onWheel = (e) => {
    context.beginPath();
    baseOnWheel(e);
    for (let x of maskData) {
        console.log(x);
        context.fillRect(x.x, x.y, x.w, x.w);
    }
};

const baseOnWheel = (event) => {
    let zoom = event.deltaY < 0 ? 1.1 : 0.1;
    const current = context.getTransform();
    // Else the image is at it minimum scale

    if (
        (zoom === 1.1 && 11 > current.a) ||
        (zoom === 0.1 && (canvas.width / image.width, canvas.height / image.height) < current.a)
    ) {
        zoom = scaleFactor + zoom;
        context.translate(currentTransformedCursor.x, currentTransformedCursor.y);
        context.scale(zoom, zoom);
        context.translate(-currentTransformedCursor.x, -currentTransformedCursor.y);

        drawImageToCanvas();
    }
};

const drawImageToCanvas = () => {
    if (context && context.canvas.id !== 'preview') {
        context.save();
        context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.restore();
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        console.log('drawing');
    }
};
```

But when the points are redrawn from onWheel(), they move because obviously my context is not the same as my cursor is not at the same coordinates anymore, the scaling can be different as the translate.

Is there a way to redraw my points at the exact same place and that they stay fixed ?

Thank you.